# VB.Net and Multiselect Box

Tags: vb.net

I have a need for being able to display one value in the multiselect box but store a different one. The API i am talking to returns me a GUID for the Item as well as its name. So i want to show user the name and use the GUID as a id or key as i need to send a call to api which include the GUID if i select or deselect it and not the text.
I have not found a way to assign a key and a text to the multiselectbox this is how i create the items currently

```
clbBucketList.Items.Add(BucketList(Index).text, False)
```

the help says object but not sure if that lets me create a key and text object or not. If the general MS control does not support this is there any 3 party control which would do this ?

Comment: What is a Multiselect Box?

Comment: Separating the data from the view is a standard programming technique, all you need is the Index.  With a collection that stores the data, looks like you already have one (BucketList).

Comment: But my BucketList has 2 values like this {
      "DocId": "leadbucket::5652A756-5B58-45A5-9566-9C85E8783440",
      "text": "Dead Leads"
    } can i use the DocID as index for the MultiSelectBox ?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to use the actual names for things rather than a name that you made up. Based on your code, it looks like you're using a `CheckedListBox`. That's what the control is called so that is what you should call it, so everyone knows what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a type that has properties for the GUID and the name and create a list of instances of that type.  You can then bind that list to your `CheckedListBox` and set the `DisplayMember` such that the property containing the name is displayed.  You can then cast the items in the `CheckedItems` collection as your type and get the GUID value from the other property.

Item type:

```
Public Class Bucket

    Public Property Guid As Guid
    Public Property Name As String

End Class
```

Binding:

```
Dim buckets As New List(Of Bucket)

For Each item In BucketList
    Dim bucket As New Bucket With {.Guid = GetGuid(item),
                                   .Name = GetName(item)}

    buckets.Add(bucket)
Next

clbBucketList.DataSource = buckets
clbBucketList.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

Normally I would say that you should set the `DataSource` last but, in my experience, that causes issues with a `CheckedListBox`.

Data retrieval:

```
Dim guids As New List(Of Guid)

For Each bucket As Bucket In clbBucketList.CheckedItems
    guids.Add(bucket.Guid)
Next
```